How to use MSOLEDB in .NET Core with Entity Framework
I recently got to know that SQL native client will no longer support from SQL Server 2022 and we may need to upgrade the provider.
Please refer to this official Microsoft document:
MSDN
My application is an ASP.NET Core Web API. I am using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. Is there any change for my application or not. If changes are there please let me know how to use provider ="MSOLEDB".
I tried:
Server=XXXXXXXXXX;Database=DEV_DB;persist security info=True;user id=DEUser;password=XXXXXXXEP;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Provider=MSOLEDB;

But it did not work and I got an error

Keyword not supported: Provider:

Code:
     public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> context)
     : base(context)
 {

 }

 //Check status of the database
 public bool IsDatabaseUp
 {
     get
     {
         bool isDbUp = false;
         try
         {
             using (var connection = this.Database.GetDbConnection())
             {
                 connection.Open();
                 isDbUp = this.Database.GetDbConnection().State == ConnectionState.Open;
                 connection.Close();

                 Console.WriteLine(" Connection Opening");
                 return isDbUp;
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             LogException(ex);
             return isDbUp;
         }
     }
 }

Please help. Thanks in advance

in my opinion there is no need to add the provider keyword to use MSOLEDBSQL . could you share your code?

Updated. Please check.

what is your code looks like in the program.cs file?

You don't need ODBC or MSOLEDB when connecting a .net application.
